# Unity crashes when window is minimized via starter

Tags: 14.04, unity

To be able to minimize a window through clicking on the icon in starter, I executed the following command from the [UbuntuUsers Wiki (German)](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/unity/Unity_Startmen%C3%BC#Minimieren-via-Klick-auf-das-Starter-Icon):

```
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ launcher-minimize-window true
```

Now when there are two ore more windows open from the same application and I click on the icon Unity crashes and I get the logon screen. For example if I open two Firefox-windows (both maximized) and click on the icon in the starter it crashes and I have to log on again.

How can I solve this issue, so that my desktop isn't crashing anymore? Expected behavior would be, that the window with the focus get minimized, instead of crashing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem did not appear in a virtual machine with a new Ubuntu, I tried to delete `~/.compiz`, `~/.config/compiz-1` and `~/.gconf`, which solves the problem. Now everything works as expected, thanks anyway! :-)